# NativeScript Sidekick Publishing IOS keeps prompting for password

Tags: ios, nativescript, publish, sidekick

Want to successfully publish our mobile app to the ios store.

When attempting to publish IOS Mobile App, it builds successfully, prompts for the store credentials, appears to login successfully, starts the publishing process and then prompts for the store password, over and over. Prompt displays: "Password (application-specific for xxxx@xxxx.com) with a "Verify" button.

Comment: Did you create an `app-specific-password' ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the App-Specific-password

- Sign in to your Apple ID account page.
- In the Security section, click
  Generate Password below App-Specific Passwords.
- Follow the steps on your screen.

Comment: Naredra. Thank you. I figured that out yesterday. Great answer.